# Python Smart UV unwrap on all objects

Tags: python, uv, select

Follow on from this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103195/smart-uv-unwrap-multiple-objects) but using v2.91.

I want to apply smart UV unwrap on all objects but if I use the code suggested in the link, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: bpy_prop_collection: attribute "active" not found
```

This is the code I used, what would be the suggested way?

```
import bpy
'''
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
for obj in objects:
    obj.select
'''
if bpy.context.selected_objects != []:
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects: #loop through all the selected objects
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
            bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle() #entering edit mode
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT') #select all objects elements
            bpy.ops.uv.smart_project() #the actual unwrapping operation
            bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle() #exiting edit mode
```

I also tried to select all objects using `obj.select` but it doesn't recognise `select`.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169928/smart-uv-project-multiple-objects-to-different-uv-maps

Comment: Just updated the code for 2.8+: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/103199/31447 Closing as dupe?